# Preencher um select com callback $getJson Asp.Net / JQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

O que eu preciso fazer é o seguinte, tenho um select com os Estados, quando a pessoa mudar esse Estado eu preciso preencher outro select com as Cidades.

Esse é o select do Estado :

```
                            <div class="input-group">

                                <select class="selectpicker dropdown" data-live-search="true" id="selectEstado">

                                    @foreach (Estado estado in Model.Cidade.Estados)
                                    {
                                        if (estado.EstadoId == Model.Cidade.EstadoId)
                                        {
                                            <option selected value="@estado.EstadoId">@estado.Nome</option>
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            <option value="@estado.EstadoId">@estado.Nome</option>
                                        }

                                    }

                                </select>

                            </div>
                        </div>
```

A função que estou tentando fazer é a seguinte :

```
    $("#selectEstado").change(function () {
    var lang = $("select option:selected").val();
    $("#language").text(lang);

    $.getJSON("/Cidade/GetCidadePorEstado?EstadoId=" + lang, null, function (cb) {
        $("#selectCidade").html(cb.CidadeNome);
        console.log(cb);
    });
});
```

Ele esta entrando na controller do C# e retornando uma model com todas as cidades, mas não sei o como proceder depois, eu tento verificar o valor do cb mas não estou conseguindo, tenho pouco conhecimento nessa área se alguém puder me dar uma força.

Desde de já eu agradeço

EDIT
Assim está agora mina função

```
    $("#selectEstado").change(function () {
    var EstadoId = $("select option:selected").val();
    $("#language").text(EstadoId);

    $.getJSON("/Cidade/GetCidadePorEstado?EstadoId=" + EstadoId, null, function (cb) {      
        $("#selectCidadeNovo").append('<option value="' + cb.CidadeNome + '">' + cb.CidadeNome + '</option>');
        console.log(cb);
    });
});
```

o `log` esta mostrando um objeto `CidadeNome:Array[141]` que são os Nomes das Cidades que eu recebi do `cb` mas não muda os nomes das Cidades.

Por padrão os dois select ja vem com valores porque esta tela e de editar cliente, então este cliente já possui uma cidade, então quando mudar o estado preciso recarregar a o select da cidade com o novo callback

Assim e o select que precisa ser alterado:

```
 <div class="form-group">

                            <div class="input-group">

                                <select class="selectpicker dropdown" data-live-search="true" id="selectCidade">

                                    @foreach (Cidade cidade in Model.Cidade.Cidades)
                                    {
                                        if (cidade.CidadeId == Model.Cidade.CidadeId)
                                        {
                                            <option selected value="@cidade.CidadeId">@cidade.Nome</option>
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            <option value="@cidade.CidadeId">@cidade.Nome</option>
                                        }

                                    }

                                </select>

                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: No meu caso o problema e adicionar a um select com a classe selectpicker , diferente da questão que você marcou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você poderá iterar o resultado de cidades que é recebido em `cb`, e ao invés de usar `html` usar [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) pra adicionar um `option` por cidade. Exemplo (partindo do princípio que o retorno é um array de cidades):

```js
var cb = ["São Paulo","Campinas", "Sorocaba"];
cb.forEach(function(cidade) {
  $("#selectCidade").append('<option value="'+cidade+'">'+cidade+'</option>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectCidade">
</select>
```

EDITADO:

```
$.getJSON("/Cidade/GetCidadePorEstado?EstadoId=" + EstadoId, null, function (cb) {      
    $("#selectCidadeNovo").clear();
    cb.CidadeNome.forEach(function(cidade){
        $("#selectCidadeNovo").append('<option value="' + cidade + '">' + cidade + '</option>');
    });
 $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh'); //Recarrega o selectpicker com os novos dados
});
```

Comment: Vou tentar aqui, acho que isso deve resolver, só uma duvida e que eu gostaria de colocar o valor do options o mesmo nome da cidade, eu vi algo do tipo
`$("#selectCidade").append(
$("<option></option>")
                .text(cidade)
                .val(cidade));`

Comment: Editei com o valor no `option` @WilliamCézar

Comment: Valeu cara vou tentar aqui, logo eu volto

Comment: Cara não deu certo , vou fazer um Edit com as mudanças e outras Duvidas

Comment: Experimente deixar o trecho de código como editei @WilliamCézar

Comment: ok tentarei agora

Comment: Não esta mudando o Select, nada do que tentei muda o select, a ultima função que você passou da para ver que vai dadndo append em cada cidade, mas não muda nada no select, lembrando que estou usando o selectpicker.

Comment: Algum erro no console?

Comment: Não nenhum , tirei o datepicker e funcionou, vou ver a documentação para ver se tem algo relacionado, mas a sua função estava certa, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Vou achar a solução para o selectpicker e adicionar a sua resposta

Comment: Por favor, fique à vontade.

Comment: Amigo ontem encontrei a solução para o datepicker, precisa recarregar-lo para que apareça os novos dados :  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
Editei sua responsta , muito obrigado.

Comment: Legal @WilliamCézar! Aprendi com essa também, tmj